# WordPress Emails & Contact Forms

Tags: forms, email, contact

I have a WordPress website and I am not receiving emails that are being submitted using contact forms. I have tried several contact form plugins, I even tried a custom contact form I coded myself with no luck. The forms were working at one point but we always had issues with the Contact Form 7 plugin, that one never worked for some reason. I am at a loss as to why this is happening. I tried sending emails out using SMTP instead of php's mail() function and that did not work either.

Comment: Have you tried to create a separate file _(outside of your WordPress instance)_ and create a custom contact form, to check if sending of mails is disabled by your host?

Comment: there is just no way to answer without guessing. You should contact your support and try to look at your mail server logs. It is also very possible that they are marked as spam

Answer (score 1):

Your could debug php mailer in WP using  franz's wpmail_exceptions plugin https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/5840282

Place the first file in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` and make sure you've set `WP_DEBUG` to `true`. You should test while logged in as administrator. Errors will be printed in main buffer so make sure to inspect any xhr requests if your form works asynchronously (Ajax).

Good luck